# ERROR [22001] ERROR: value too long for type character varying(50)

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, powershell

I'm facing an issue while trying to transfer data from a MongoDB collection to a PostgreSQL table using PowerShell. Below is my script along with the error I encounter.

Script:

```
# Export data from MongoDB to a JSON file

mongoexport --uri "mongodb+srv://xxx:xxx@xxxsandbox.xlx.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority" --db Testx --collection xx --out xx.json

# Read JSON content and convert it to PowerShell objects

$Objekte = Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\xx\Desktop\xx.json" | ConvertFrom-Json 

# PostgreSQL connection details

$MyServer = "xx"
$MyPort  = "5xx"
$MyDB = "Moxxen"
$MyUid = "pxxs"
$MyPass = "x"
$Tabelle = "CREATE TABLE Rezepte (
                id text PRIMARY KEY,
                Anleitung VARCHAR(50),
                Name VARCHAR(20),
                Utensilien VARCHAR(20),
                Zutaten VARCHAR(20),
                Mengen VARCHAR(20));"

$PgConnectionString = "Driver={PostgreSQL Unicode(x64)};Server=$MyServer;Port=$MyPort;Database=$MyDB;Uid=$MyUid;Pwd=$MyPass;"
$PgConn = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection;
$PgConn.ConnectionString = $PgConnectionString;

# Check if the table exists

try {
    $PgConn.Open()
    $command = $PgConn.CreateCommand()
    $checkTableQuery = "SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_schema = 'public'
    AND table_name = 'rezepte');"
    $command.CommandText = $checkTableQuery
    $tableExists = $command.ExecuteScalar()

    if ($tableExists -eq 0) {
        $command.CommandText = $Tabelle
        $null = $command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Write-Host "Table creation successful."

    } else {
        Write-Host "Table already exists."
    }
} finally {
    $PgConn.Close()
}

# Check if the table has data

try {
    $PgConn.Open()
    $checkDataQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM rezepte;"
    $command.CommandText = $checkDataQuery
    $rowCount = $command.ExecuteScalar()

    if ($rowCount -gt 0) {
        $deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM rezepte;"
        $command.CommandText = $deleteQuery
        $null = $command.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Write-Host "Existing data deleted successfully."
    } else {
        Write-Host "Table is empty. No data to delete."
    }
} finally {
    
    $PgConn.Close()
}

# Insert data into the PostgreSQL table

try {
    $PgConn.Open()

 foreach ($Objekt in $Objekte) {
        $insertQuery = @"
            INSERT INTO rezepte (id, Anleitung, Name, Utensilien, Zutaten, Mengen)
            VALUES ('$($Objekt._id.'$oid')', '$($Objekt.Anleitung)', '$($Objekt.Name)', '$($Objekt.Utensilien)', '$($Objekt.Zutaten)', '$($Objekt.Mengen)');
"@

        $command = $PgConn.CreateCommand()
        $command.CommandText = $insertQuery
        $null = $command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    }

    Write-Host "Data insertion successful."

} finally {
    $PgConn.Close()
}
```

The output with the error:

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> C:\Users\yalhares\Desktop\mont.ps1

Table creation successful.

Table is empty. No data to delete.

Exception when calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with 0 argument(s):  "ERROR [22001] ERROR: value too long for type character varying(50);

Error while executing the query"

In C:\Users\xx\Desktop\mont.ps1:82 Zeichen:9
$null = $command.ExecuteNonQuery()

I have run the script with the data type variants VARCHAR(100), VARCHAR(500), VARCHAR(1000) and text, but the error persists.

The error indicates that the value being inserted into the _id column exceeds the length specified in the PostgreSQL table definition. However, as you can see below, the _id column has only 24 characters, which makes no sense.

This is the output of $Objects:

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $objects

**_id        : @{$oid=6470604f624c0c04f74f4d0f}**

Anleitung  : Lege eine Scheibe Brot auf das Brett und bestreiche es mit Butter

Name       : Butterbrot

Utensilien : {Brett, Messer}

Zutaten    : {Brot, Butter}

Mengen     : {75g, 20g}

And this is the output of ($Objekt._id.'$oid'):

**6470604f624c0c04f74f4d0f**

All columns in the Postgresql table have been successfully loaded, except the _id column

I appreciate any hint or solution to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CREATE TABLE` statement defines the `Anleitung` column as being of max length 50, but the value you're trying to insert exceeds that length:

```
PS ~> 'Lege eine Scheibe Brot auf das Brett und bestreiche es mit Butter'.Length
65
```

Change the column type and it'll work:

```
                Anleitung TEXT,
```